# Is there a Python function that does what mapply do in R

Tags: python, r, pandas

Is there a function in Python that can do what Mapply do in R?

Basically I have a list of n inputs(each entry is a dataframe) for a function and corresponding lists(each list has the length of n) of parameters.

In each parameter lists, the position of each parameter corresponds to the respective position of input in the input list.

Now I wish to obtain the result in the exact order of the way I put my input, either in the form of a list with each element a dataframe(or matrix or whatever) or just one dataframe with all result appended. This is easily achievable in R using Mapply, but in python, I haven't got the luck to find any function that does the trick.

I haven't try this but one of the solution that i thought of is to pd.concat all lists(including input list and parameter lists) I got into one bulky list by column and apply the function to each row where I'll extract each element of the row to fill the function.

This might work but it would look quite stupid if there is actually one-line solution.

This is how I would deal with the problem in R:

```
result <- mapply(FUN = function(input, parameter1, parameter2) function_of_interest(input, parameter1, parameter2), input = input_list, parameter1 = parameter1_list, parameter2 = parameter2_list,... )
```

Comment: You probably want to use `zip` in a list comprehension, but IMO your question is too broad to provide a specific answer. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, this example of `mapply` in R:

```
A <- c(1, 2, 3)
B <- c(2, 3, 4)

my_multiplication <- function(x,y){return(x*y)}

C <- mapply(my_multiplication, A, B)
```

could be roughly equivalent to this Python code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]

def my_multiplication(x, y):
    return x * y

c = map(my_multiplication, a, b)
```

The `c` is now a so called [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator). If I oversimplify, `c` can be viewed as a function that returns:

`a[0] * b[0]` on first call,
 `a[1] * b[1]` on second call,
 `a[2] * b[2]` on third (and last) call

```
i = 0
message = 'a[{}] * b[{}] = {} * {} = {}'

for result in c:
    print(message.format(i, i ,a[i], b[i], result))
    i += 1
```

prints

```
a[0] * b[0] = 1 * 2 = 2
a[1] * b[1] = 2 * 3 = 6
a[2] * b[2] = 3 * 4 = 12
```

Comment: No, that's `outer(A, B, "*")` in R. `mapply` basically is R's version of `map`. The result should be `[2, 6, 12]`.

Comment: I would try to avoid any for loop for the sake of performance but thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Potato_Noodle that doesn't make sense. `mapply` is also a loop and, fundamentally, you need *some kind*  of loop for this operation.

Comment: I understand the point though, some approach can for example cause the same immutable variables to be created all over again. I think @Potato_Noodle meant it only in the sense that we need to be sure we're avoiding bad practices.

Comment: As pointed out in my original comment, one would typically use zip together with a list comprehension `[my_multiplication(x,y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]` or a generator expression `(my_multiplication(x,y) for x, y in zip(a, b))`.

Comment: Comprehensions are definitely used more often, they are much more "general purpose" kind of tool, which is partly why they don't feel like the right answer here. The question was specifically for Python function equivalent to mapply from R. Comprehension is rather a control flow tool than a function.

But I'm considering expanding the answer so it would also include Python versions of apply, lapply and sapply, along with equivalent behavior achieved using comprehensions. It could be nice but maybe too much off-topic.

Comment: Coincidentally, `Map` in R is a wrapper to `mapply` (equivalent to passing `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`).

Answer (score 1):

My answer seems to be a modification of the answer given by @Paolo42, which just wraps the "map" function with a call to "list" to get rid of the loop:

```
>>> list(map(my_multiplication, A, B) )
[2, 6, 12]
```

I also liked the list comprehension solution given by @Alexander, but I also appreciate the comment from @Paolo42.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is important that `mapply` takes in multiple lists and returns the output in one list.[fn^1] In R, dataframe columns are lists so you can easily use `mapply` (and its cousin `lapply`) to modify dataframes. 

[fn^1]: Yes, by default it simplifies, but based on my usage I nearly always wanted a list.

So either wrap the map call in a list as above or put that in the function as well.